# Problem on displaying the variables of a require file in PHP

Tags: php

My file includes/global.inc.php contains info about the DB and it is just like below

```
<?php
$glob['dbdatabase'] = 'xxx';
$glob['dbhost'] = 'localhost';
$glob['dbpassword'] = 'xxx';
$glob['dbusername'] = 'xxx';
?>
```

In my new PHP file I did that

```
<?php
require('includes/global.inc.php');
$host = $glob['dbhost'];
$user = $glob['dbusername'];
$pass = $glob['dbpassword'];
$database = $glob['dbdatabase'];
?>
```

but it is wrong because it won't let me connect. How can I assign correct the variables?

**UPDATE**

I pasted more variables.

Comment: are you sure the problem exists here? have you tried hard coding the $host, $user, $pass ect.

Comment: Yes, I put the values directly and worked

Comment: Is that the exact content of the global.inc.php file? Because it doesn't define `$glob[ 'dbusername' ]` and it uses `$glob[ 'dbdatabase' ]` instead of `$glob[ 'database' ]`.

Comment: Forgot <?php in file #2?

Comment: The content on the global.inc.php are the correct login details to access my database...

Comment: @Nikolai sure, but is the typo and/or the missing `$glob[ 'dbusername' ]` the issue?

Comment: What's the error message and the code you use to connect to the db?

Comment: To all of you, problem soved, I wrote in the documentation that I had to include another file. Very strange but it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo there.

It should be

`$database = $glob['dbdatabase'];` but not `$database = $glob['database'];`

Also, your `$glob['dbusername']` seems to be not defined anywhere.
`

Comment: Problem soved, I wrote in the documentation that I had to include another file. Very strange but it worked. Thank you.